# Is it OK to have kerberos-sec port open to the Internet in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, firewall, vnc, kerberos

I’ve just bought my first Mac I want to connect it directly to the Internet in a colocation facility.

Running `nmap` against it shows:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-18 21:54 GMT
Nmap scan report for foo.bar (123.45.67.89)
Host is up (0.00036s latency).
rDNS record for 123.45.67.89: 89.67.45.123.in-addr.arpa
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
88/tcp   open  kerberos-sec
5900/tcp open  vnc
MAC Address: 01:23:45:67:89:AB (Apple)
```

I’ve deliberately started the SSH and VNC services.

What has started kerberos?

Is it okay for that port to be open to the Internet?

If not, how can I close it? When I tried setting up the firewall, the only applications were Remote Management (VNC) and Remote Login (SSH).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `kerberos-sec` on port `88` is an authentication method connected to AFP (Apple Filing Protocol) or SMB (Samba) file sharing. If you wish to disable it, you can [as per the instructions on this site](http://simon.heimlicher.com/articles/2008/03/20/kdcmond). This should work for Mac OS X 10.6.8 and below:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.kdcmond.plist
```

For Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) and above the command would be:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.Kerberos.kdc.plist
```

If you wish to enable it again, just change `unload` to `load` like this:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.Kerberos.kdc.plist
```

Answer (score 3):

I had used the *File Share* feature earlier and turned it off, but somehow the port was still open. So I just went there again, checked and unchecked it and after running `nmap` it was closed!

**System Preferences > Sharing > File Share: set it to off**

[image]

Comment: Since the only thing I shared was the public folder, I just turned off file & screen sharing and this also solved my port 88 already in use issue with some application using docker-compose in development.